# How to iterate one dataframe based on a mapping file in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

| Serial No. | Company 1 | Company 2 | Company 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | NA | 2 | NA |
| 02 | 2 | NA | 5 |
| 03 | NA | NA | 4 |
| 04 | 1 | NA | NA |
| 05 | NA | 4 | NA |

I have a data structure like this where the column headings represent some companies and the row headings represents consumers who buy the products. 'NA' representing no purchase for that company's products by the consumer.
I have a second mapping file where the companies are represented as row headings as follows -

| Company | Country | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | UK | FMCG |
| Company 2 | UK | FMCG |
| Company 3 | India | FMCG |
| Company 4 | US | Nicotine |

The data set is for over 10000 consumers and 1000 companies. I'm getting the market share for different countries and categories using the aggregate function and mapping file.
I want to make a look to iterate values in the first data-frame to change the share for different countries and categories. The idea is to make a loop where I can choose which country's (or category) share needs to be changed along with the share and then to use the mapping file to iterate values for companies in those countries (or category). The values need to be changes for only those consumers who buy the products from companies belonging to that country (or category).

Can someone suggest how can this be done in R (preferably) or Python?

Edit:
Before iteration I will use the aggregate function in R to get the shares for a country (or category) like this -

| Country | Share |
| --- | --- |
| UK | 0.33 |
| US | 0.02 |
| IN | 0.41 |
| IR | 0.11 |
| PK | 0.13 |

In the loop I want to be able to specify the share for some country (say UK) to whatever is required (say 0.5). The mapping file will be used to iterate values to the first data structure where people have bought products from companies in UK.

The final output will be something like this.

| Country | Share |
| --- | --- |
| UK | 0.50 |
| US | 0.00 |
| IN | 0.38 |
| IR | 0.11 |
| PK | 0.01 |

Comment: Can you add how you are planning to modify the company shares? Are you planning to include them into your "mapping table"?

Comment: The plan is to iterate the values in the first table using a loop which will change the shares for each company, country and category until the specified share is reached. The mapping file just acts as a dictionary to see which company belongs to what country and category

Comment: Can you show your expected output based on the data given in your question?

Comment: The final result will be just a table with first column as country (or category) and the second column as the share for each country (or category)

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the exact expected output for the data that you have shared?

Comment: What do you mean by "share"? For instance, is it *"number of rows of this country divided by total number of rows"*? There have been two requests for your expected output, please be literal and clear: if you must, manually create a `data.frame` that has the countries and shares given this sample data.

Comment: I have edited the post. 
By share I mean the market share. Basically the sum of all products sold divided by the sum of products sold by companies in that country.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess: ultimately, this is a combination of reshape from wide to long, then `merge`/join, and finally aggregation/summarizing by group. If you need more information for either operation, using those key-words (on SO) will provide very useful information.

### base R (and `reshape2`)

```r
## reshape
dat1melted <- reshape2::melt(dat1, "Serial No.", variable.name = "Company")
dat1melted$Company <- as.character(dat1melted$Company)
dat1melted <- dat1melted[!is.na(dat1melted$value),]
dat1melted
#    Serial No.   Company value
# 2          02 Company 1     2
# 4          04 Company 1     1
# 6          01 Company 2     2
# 10         05 Company 2     4
# 12         02 Company 3     5
# 13         03 Company 3     4

## merge
dat1merged <- merge(dat1melted, dat2, by = "Company", all.x = TRUE)
dat1merged
#     Company Serial No. value Country Category
# 1 Company 1         02     2      UK     FMCG
# 2 Company 1         04     1      UK     FMCG
# 3 Company 2         01     2      UK     FMCG
# 4 Company 2         05     4      UK     FMCG
# 5 Company 3         02     5   India     FMCG
# 6 Company 3         03     4   India     FMCG

## aggregate by group
aggregate(value ~ Country, data = dat1merged, FUN = sum)
#   Country value
# 1   India     9
# 2      UK     9
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
dat1 %>%
  ## reshape
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-`Serial No.`, names_to = "Company") %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  ## merge
  left_join(., dat2, by = "Company") %>%
  ## aggregate by group
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarize(value = sum(value))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Country value
#   <chr>   <int>
# 1 India       9
# 2 UK          9
```

Comment: That's the first part of it before the loop begins. After using the aggregate with sum command when we get the final shares, I want to make a loop where I can specify the share for a country and it iterates the first table to make changes to share until the desired share is reached.